# Pardot with Salesforce

Tags: professional-edition, pardot

I have  a Pick-list  field name as Sales Director in which 5  members are  there  and there is a Lead Status field  in lead object. What i want want is that whenever a   new lead is created and if the status is new than automatically  an email will be shoot  to the Sales director which i select  in the pick list.

**Note:- I am using Professional Edition**

Comment: What does this has to do with Pardot?

Comment: @RobinDeBondt  this will  Automate email notification (to Sales Director )  from pardot when a lead status is set to New in salesforce.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand it correctly, you choosing a Sales Director + Lead Status being new should trigger sending an email.
Question: DOes the picklist contain names or emails of Sales Directors.
Assuming that the picklist has emails, you should be able to do this with 2 workflows. General idea as bellow:
1st - To write the picklist value to a field of type email.
2nd workflow to actually send the email, using the email address stored in the email field.

Even if the picklist contains names workflows should work.

Thanks
Priti

Comment: Workflow will not work in PE .